# Change Mouse state with AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouseevent, addeventlistener

Is it possible to change the state of a mouse using actions script. So if the user clicks and holds down the left mouse button `MOUSE_DOWN` is it possible for actionscript to change the mouse state to `MOUSE_UP` without the user releasing the mouse?

I have a MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start);
```

but in the start function I would like to set the mouse state to MOUSE_UP even if the user holds down on the button.

```
function start ():void {

      trace("You have pressed the mouse button");
      //SET MOUSE TO MOUSE_UP
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make mouse button unclicked , but You can dispatch MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP on clip without any mouse interaction .

```
clip.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
```

But manualy dispatch needs to add mouse x and y values.

also , note that You can use function :

```
var dspArray:Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(stage.mouseX,mouseY));
for each(var dsp:DisplayObject in dspArray){
    dsp.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
}
```

but dont forget that when user will release mouse button , it will also dispatch MouseEvent.

Comment: Great I will look into using dispatchEvent! +1 Checked.

Comment: But as i said , You have to add x and y coords manualy to read them in function and for this use globalToLocal and localToGlobal methods.